# HTML5 site implementation

Tags: html, browser, compatibility

My question is borne out of my confusion on (still incomplete, with existing features still evolving?) HTML5 support in different browsers, all the resources available on how to implement existing features and simple practicality.

1) How do you go about implementing HTML5 only features in your web-site? Do you do some kind of browser/version check at first access and notify user that he should install some other browser (though cumbersome and uncomfortable to the user)?

2) Is there a way to check availability of HTML5 features in user's browser dynamically (version X of Chrome does not support it, next might and it should work then) and easily without some significant computing overhead and significant coding?

3) Assuming the answer to 2) is yes, what to do about changes in spec that might occur in the future? (The check would say fine, the browser does implement e.g. WebGL, but my implementation would run into errors as there would be some changes between the spec I had used during development and spec that was enhanced in the W3C process and would make my implementation incompatible)

Comment: To number 3: the spec could change, but those features that are implemented in browsers are pretty solid. You'd have more troubles with browser inconsistency than you would with spec changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. to start using html5, make sure that the first line in your html is `<!doctype html>` this tells the browser that you are speaking in the language of **html5**
2. this google-hosted [html5 shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) helps to ensure that the new html5 tags work in older browsers and as someone already pointed out, you can and dare I say it, *should* use [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to test the browser's CSS rendering capabilities
3. This is just something you need to keep abreast of yourself unfortunately ;) The way I look at it, if the spec changes in a big way, lets say they decided to remove the `<article>`, there will be a lot of chatter online and you are likely to read about it

I recommend that you take a look at [html5-boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com). It's a **A rock-solid default for HTML5 awesome.**` It's a starter kit with template html, CSS and Javascript files for building an html5 website.

Answer (score 1):

This is useful: http://www.modernizr.com/

As for 3: I think that's just a risk of using a technology before it's out of spec.

Comment: seems interesting and I will sure have a deeper look at it. I'd prefer a less concise answer though. thanks.

Comment: You're right, I should have provided more information - sorry about that. modernizr can be kind of confusing at a glance. I use it quite a bit if you have any questions; feel free to ask!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at modernizr, it's a js library that will do various feature detection tests and gives you a way to query whether or not to use a particular feature.  You can also load specific js files with modernizr.load based on whether a feature is supported in the browser.

http://www.modernizr.com/

Tutorial: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taking-advantage-of-html5-and-css3-with-modernizr/